# (Ubuntu Server 16.04) Slow sending smtp with attachment

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

[image]
Hi! I have postfix + dovecot

How to speed up the upload attachment file from smtp?
Inbox mail very fast and send mail without attachment very fast. Send with attachment very slow :(

Upload 20Mb = up 1 minute...

Comment: What are the speed on your internet connection ? What does a 20Mb up- or down-load to/from an other server take ?

Comment: My local network 100 Mbps, This server is proxy, samba, ftp and fine working. Problem only with speed send mail with attachments... If I'll send many letters with attachments speed is more reduced...  20Mb = more than 1 minute!

Comment: Please, help me...

Comment: imap through the same